# NuGet AzureServiceBus issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, win-universal-app, servicebus

I'm working to a IoT project with Azure. My purpouse is checking "feedback" message sent from iotHub while I'm uploading data to it.

To doing so I was tring to install WindowsAzure.ServiceBus (versione 5.0, but tried even previously versions)NuGet package. I'm getting those type of errors:

```
    Il pacchetto System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 4.0.4.403061554 non è compatibile con uap10.0.14393 (UAP,Version=v10.0.14393). Il pacchetto System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 4.0.4.403061554 supporta: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)

Il pacchetto WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 5.0.0 non è compatibile con uap10.0.14393 (UAP,Version=v10.0.14393)/win10-arm-aot. Il pacchetto WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 5.0.0 supporta: net46 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6)
```

For who isn't italian, it says "The packet xxx isn't compatible with xxx".

So I searched in Internet and found some "solutions":

1) cleare NuGet cache and re-download it. Done that, issue still present.

2) Manually installing .NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5 . For 4.6, done succefully, but 4.5 isn't avaible... so problem didn't solve either (even worst it doesn't recognize my .NET Framework 4.6).

So I tried to search deeper, I have changed the minimum version of Windows 10 where my UWP project is builted but nothing changed... so  this is the reason I'm asking help to you.

Many thanks!

PS: my .NET Framework, various update are done succefully, I just can't install this packet... VS Studio 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WindowsAzure.ServiceBus is a package for .Net Framework applications.

There is a similar .Net Standard package [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) for .Net Framework, .Net Standard and .Net Core applications.

Based on you project type, you can choose between these packages.

Comment: Your answer saved my life, now I have discovered what I was doing wrong... tring to instal this package in a UWP app.... but may I ask: is it possible to have a library similar for uwp? I mean... can I work with service bus with uwp? thank you very very much ^^

Comment: Based on what I analysed, Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus works for UWP apps :)